# Flask Jinja2 template dictionary in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I am working with the following dictionary in a flask app and cannot figure out how to select the nested dictionary values in a Jinja2 template.

```
dict = {"key1": {"subkey1":"subvalue1","subkey2":"subvalue2","subkey3":"subvalue3"}, "key2": {"subkey1":"subvalue1","subkey2":"subvalue2","subkey3":"subvalue3"}}
```

I am able to get at each value in a python shell like so:

```
print(dict['key1']['subkey1'])
print(dict['key1']['subkey2'])
print(dict['key1']['subkey3'])
```

I am sending the dict to the template like so:

```
return render_template('template.html', dict=dict)
```

And then in my attempts at a template I have:

```
{% for item in dict %}
    <td>{{ item.subkey1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.subkey2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.subkey3 }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

But this does not return the subvalues as I hoped.

Comment: Why would it be any different? If you're having problems, you should show your template and the `render_template` call.

Comment: Exactly as @DanielRoseman pointed out... Share the part where `dict` is implemented in template html.

Comment: Sorry I have added a bit more info to my question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{% for key1,item1 in dict.items() %}
   {% for key2,nested_item in item1.items() %}
      <td> {{nested_item}} </td>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`dict.item()` is used for fetching keys and items in dictionary `dict`.

1 level of loop is required to access a dictionary and 2 level of loops are required to access dictionary of dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Prashant that is exactly what I was looking for. Apologies if it seems like a really NOOB thing but I just couldn't get my head around it! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to Jinja at all.

When you iterate over a dict with `for x in y`, you only get the keys, not the values. If you want to iterate over the values, you need to do that explicitly:

```
{% for item in dict.values() %}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this has helped me with the subvalues. How can I access the key1 for example in the same for loop?